# CSS Perspective and scale animation for font awesome icons

Tags: html, css

Hello can someone point me to the right direction? I am trying to create an animation where icons are zooming in front of the screen and they should be endless. Problem is I can't get it right the correct timing. Here's my progress

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="300" data-default-tab="html,result" data-slug-hash="KKWqwBe" data-user="asokaaso2" style="height: 300px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/asokaaso2/pen/KKWqwBe">
  Untitled</a> by Mang Kanor (<a href="https://codepen.io/asokaaso2">@asokaaso2</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am not clear what the problem is - what would be 'correct timing'?

Comment: I want it look like the icons are infinite and just keeps on appearing.